# Cant save Read Stream to Amazon S3 using aws2js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, stream, amazon-s3

In my node.js app I'm uploading a file (which is saved to local filesystem -> /tmp/) from which I create a Stream of, to store that file into my S3bucket using [aws2js (Amazon CLI bindings)](https://github.com/SaltwaterC/aws2js).The problem starts with trying to initially save the file to S3 with [putStream(...)](https://github.com/SaltwaterC/aws2js/wiki/s3.putStream%28%29), before I do any further manipulations. (using [´putFile(filepath)´](https://github.com/SaltwaterC/aws2js/wiki/s3.putFile%28%29) works!)

The Entry in my Bucket is created and no error is given with the callback. But no file-content has been saved and the Entry has 0 bytes.

Following, my code;

```
....
var fileStream=fs.createReadStream(file.path),
    savePath = _makeSavePath( file.name );                  

s3.putStream(savePath, fileStream, 'public-read', {'content-type': file.type.mime, 'content-length':file.length}, function (err, s3File) {
    if (err){
        console.error(err);
        fileGetCB(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("SAVED TO S3 '"+savePath+"'!!");

    //do further manipulations with fileStream
});
...
```

I can assure, that `file` is initialized and that the file at file.path exists.

The reason why I'm using a stream and not using `S3.putFile(path)` is because I'll be further manipulating the file. By using a stream I could later reuse so that not every module has to re-read the whole file (maybe its not even possible to 'reuse' a stream, but thats not the problem (yet).. )

I am very helpful for any hand in any direction, since I cant figure out why this isn't working for 4days of try&fail. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I made a mistake in my original post on GitHub. aws2js changed internally the way that a Stream is uploaded to S3.

As for node.js v0.6.9, it isn't unstable per se, but it has a broken handling of [Expect: 100-continue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2636).

Answer (score 0):

I [took up contact with the owner](https://github.com/SaltwaterC/aws2js/issues/18) of the project and he pointed out, that the way how node handles streams has changed internally. He also pointed out, that node0.6.9 isn't stable at the moment.
I tested my script with Node 0.6.5 (the version right after the big shift) and aws2js@0.6.4 beeing used. I'm using the code, as I described it above and; IT WORKS! YAY! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may like to take a look at AwsSum and this example from the example script repo:

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/
- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum-scripts/blob/master/bin/amazon-s3-upload.js

AwsSum can stream files like how you want using fs.createReadStream(), works on all versions of node v0.6.x and is also actively maintained.

Let me know how you get on and whether you need any help.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of AwsSum. :)